# Time conversion in oracle DBA scheduler

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

A silly question...
I had created a job where the timezone is in **Australia/Sydney**,now they need it in **Central Standard Time (in USA)**. So instead of Australia/Sydney should I just replace it with the term CST?Will it be correct?
or anything else is needed?

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
   job_name           =>  'update_sales',
   job_type           =>  'STORED_PROCEDURE',
   job_action         =>  'OPS.SALES_PKG.UPDATE_SALES_SUMMARY',
   start_date         =>  '28-APR-16 07.00.00 PM Australia/Sydney',
   repeat_interval    =>  'FREQ=DAILY;
   end_date           =>  '20-NOV-17 07.00.00 PM Australia/Sydney',
   auto_drop          =>   FALSE,
   job_class          =>  'batch_update_jobs',
   comments           =>  'My new job');
END;
/
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'they need' ? Do they need to _specify_ times in CST in code like the snippet from your question or do they need times in cst when _querying_ info about jobs from the scheduler ?

Comment: I assume you're referring to Australian CST. First, is the intention to have the job run at 7:00 PM CST or at the equivalent of 7:00 PM EST? Also, in Australia the CST zone is the Northern Territory and South Australia. NT does not observe daylight savings time while SA does. In the EST zone Queensland doesn't observe DST but the others do. So by "CST" do you mean NT CST or SA CST? The difference between Australian EST and Australian CST is nominally 1/2 an hour (EST is nominally GMT+10, CST is nominally CST+9.5 - with daylight saving adjustments in SA, NSW, VIC, and ACT). Please clarify.

Comment: I need it in Central Standard Time (in USA).Please help

Comment: And when do you need to job to run? Do you need it to run at 7:00 PM US Central Standard Time, or do you need it to run at the equivalent of 7:00 PM Australian EST? US CST is GMT-6 hours, while Australian EST is GMT+10 hours - thus, there's either a -16 hour difference (travelling west) or a +8 hour difference (travelling east). ???

Comment: I need that to run @ 7:00 PM US Central Standard Time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer:

```
BEGIN
      DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
       job_name           =>  'ENTRY_TIME',
       job_type           =>  'STORED_PROCEDURE',
       job_action         =>  'PK_ENTRY_TIME.PROC_ENTRY_TIME',
       start_date         =>  '24-MAY-16 07.00.00 AM America/Chicago',
       repeat_interval    =>  'FREQ=DAILY',
       end_date           =>  '20-NOV-99 07.00.00 AM America/Chicago',
       auto_drop          =>   FALSE,
      comments           =>  'My new job');
    END;
    /
```